# joining 3 table and group theme getting repetitive result

Tags: sql-server, linq

I'm trying to join 3 table  tbRecipe - tbImageRecipe - tbMaterial and group theme into one big list.

This is my code:

```
 var result = (from c in db.tbRecipe.Distinct()                                 
                              join s in db.tbImageRecipe.Distinct()
                              on c.ID equals s.RecipeID
                              join material in db.tbMaterial.Distinct() on 
 c.ID equals material.RecipeID 
                              group new {  s.ImageUrl, 
  material.MaterialName,material.MaterialValue,material.RecipeID }  by new { 
  c.ID, c.Name, c.CaloryValue, c.CoockTime ,c.ViewCount, c.VideoURL} 
                             into g
                             orderby g.Key.ViewCount descending
                              select g).Take(10).ToList();

                var lstItems = new List<ImageModel>();
                var MaterialItems = new List<MatrialModel>();


                foreach (var r in result)
                {
                    var item = new ImageModel { ImageRecipes = new 
          List<tbImageRecipe>() , ItemsofMaterial = new List<tbMaterial>() }  
  ;


                    foreach (var s in r)
                    {
                        item.ImageRecipes.Add(new tbImageRecipe
                        {
                            ImageUrl = s.ImageUrl
                        });
                        item.ItemsofMaterial.Add(new tbMaterial
                        {
                            MaterialName = s.MaterialName,
                            MaterialValue = s.MaterialValue,
                            RecipeID = s.RecipeID
                        });
                    }
                    lstItems.Add(item);


                }

                return Json(lstItems.Distinct());
```

I'm getting multiple result's like this:
the result below have 3 image url in database and one material item:

```
  "ImageRecipes": [
        {
            "ID": 0,
            "ImageUrl": "https://findicons.com/files/icons/1187/pickin_time/128/lettuce.png",
            "RecipeID": null
        },
        {
            "ID": 0,
            "ImageUrl": "https://findicons.com/files/icons/1187/pickin_time/128/lettuce.png",
            "RecipeID": null
        },
        {
            "ID": 0,
            "ImageUrl": "https://findicons.com/files/icons/1187/pickin_time/128/lettuce.png",
            "RecipeID": null
        }
    ],
    "ItemsofMaterial": [
        {
            "ID": 0,
            "MaterialName": "نمک",
            "MaterialValue": "200 گرم",
            "RecipeID": 9
        },
        {
            "ID": 0,
            "MaterialName": "نمک",
            "MaterialValue": "200 گرم",
            "RecipeID": 9
        },
        {
            "ID": 0,
            "MaterialName": "نمک",
            "MaterialValue": "200 گرم",
            "RecipeID": 9
        }
    ]
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That makes my eyes spin! I think some custom SQL is what the doctor ordered here. Can we see the SQL that LINQ is producing please? It does a lot of it's work using `apply` so I'm guessing it's electing the wrong iterator somewhere. The SQL will reveal that for us.

Answer (score 2):

So you have a sequence of `Recipes`, each `Recipe` is identified by a unique primary key.

You also have a table with `ImageRecipes`, identified by unique primary key. There is a one-to-many relation between `Recipes` and `ImageRecipes`: every `Recipe` has zero or more `ImageRecipes`, every `ImageRecipe` belongs to exactly one `Recipe` using a foreign key.

Similarly you have a `Materials` with a one-to-many between `Recipe` and `Materials`, every `Material` belongs to exactly one `Recipe`.

Whenever you want an "item with (some or all of) his many sub-items", like a "School with his Students", a "Customer with his Orders", or an "Order with its OrderLines", you should consider to use [Enumerable.GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin?view=netframework-4.7.2). In the parameters you specify the primary key and the foreign key, and you select the properties that you want in your end result.

By the way: why are you using `Distinct()`? All elements in your table have a unique primary key, don't they, so they are already unique.

```
var lstItems = recipes.GroupJoin(imageRecipes, // GroupJoin recipes and imagerecipes
    recipe => recipe.Id,                       // from every recipe take the primary key
    imageRecipe => imageRecipe.recipeId        // from every imageRecipe take the foreign key
    (recipe, imageRecipes) => new              // from every recipy with all its imageRecipes
    {                                          // make one new:
        Recipe = recipe,
        ImageRecipes = imageRecipes,
    })

    // Groupjoin the Materials:
    .GroupJoin(tblMaterials,
    joinResult => joinResult.Recipe.Id    // from the Recipe take the primary key
    material => material.RecipeId         // the the Material take the foreign key
    (joinResult, materials) => new        // from every Recipe-with-its-imageRecipes
    {                                     // and the matching materials, make one new:
        // select the image properties you plan to use
        Id = joinResult.Image.Id,
        Name = joinResult.Image.Name,
        ...

        // all ImageMaterials of this Image
        ImageMaterials = joinResult.ImageMaterials
            .Where(imageMaterial => ...)       // if you want only some ImageMaterials of this Image
            .Select(imageMaterial => new
            {
                // select the imageMaterials you plan to use
                Id = imageMaterial.Id,
                ...
            })
            .ToList(),

            Materials = materials.Select(material => new
            {
                ... // the material properties you plan to use.
            })
            .ToList(),    
    }
```

Result: Recipes, each with its ImageRecipes and its Materials.

After your inner join you do a strange groupby which I don't understand. Alas you forgot to write the exact specification and I can't extract the specification from your query, as this query does not give your desired result. So you'll have to do the groupby yourseld

Comment: always love your answers!)

Comment: Well thank you! So you're the one who is always doing the +1!